# C Compiling error in switch statement

Tags: c, linux, scope, switch-statement

I'm programming in C and i got some errors that i was not really expecting and i can quite figure it out. The idea is to create a menu with a switch statement to call functions by user input. I got no errors in the functions but i get this:

"expected declaration before ‘}’ token 
}"

and this one:

"case label ‘14’ not within a switch statement", this error repeats for every label in the switch statement. I checked the brackets and they were all completed with a open and closed brackets.

I'm using sublime-text 2.0 as my editor and builder and Linux as my OS

```
int main(){
char string[TMAXSTR], string2[TMAXSTR];
int option, ch;

for(option=0, ch=0;option<15;){

    printf("Escolha uma opção:\n1 - Strconcat (concatenacao de strings)\n2 - Capicua\n3 - Strcmp (Comparacao de Strings)\n4 - Stricmp (transforma caratares em minusculas e compara)\n5 - Strdelc (apaga um determinado caracter)\n6 - Trimright (apaga espaços em branco a direita\n7 - Trimleft (apaga espaços a esquerda\n8 - Trimmiddle (apaga espaços no meio\n9 - Inverter (inverte uma string)\n10 - Findchar (devolve o numero de vezes que um determinado carater aparece na string\n11 - IndiceChar (devolve a posicao de um determinado carater\n12 - Maisculas (Converte a string em maiusculas\n13 - Minusculas (converte a string em minusculas)\n14 - Strstr\n15 - Sair");   

    switch(option){
            case 1:puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                   printf("%s",strconcat(string, string2);break;

            case 2:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   if(capi(string))
                        puts("E capicua");break;
                    else
                        puts("Nao capicua");break;

            case 3:puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                   if(strcmp(string, string2)==0)
                        puts("Sao iguais");break;
                   else
                        puts("Sao diferentes");break;

            case 4:puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);

                   if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                        puts("Sao iguais");break;
                   else
                        puts("Sao diferentes");break;
                    }

            case 5:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza o carater a verificar: "); scanf(" %c",&ch);
                   printf("A string sem o carater é: %s",strdelc(string,ch));break;

            case 6:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A nova string é: %s", trimright(string));break;

            case 7:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A nova string é: %s", trimleft(string));break;

            case 8: puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A nova string é: %s", trimmiddle(string));break;

            case 9:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A string invertida é: %s", meuinverter(string));break;

            case 10:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("O carater aparece: %dx", findchar(string, ch));break;

            case 11:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    puts("Introduza o carater: "); scanf(" %c",&ch);
                    printf("O indice do carater é: %d", indchr(string,ch));break;

            case 12:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A string em maisculas é: %s", mas(string));break;

            case 13:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A string em minusculas é: %s", min(string));break;

            case 14:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                    printf("%s", mystrstr(string,string2));break;

            default: puts("Invalido");break;        
        }
    }
return 0;}
```

Comment: is your code really written like this?

Comment: Is there a line number that comes with the first error?

Comment: Look at this line (3rd line in the `case 1` option: "printf("%s",strconcat(string, string2);break;". There's a closing `)` missing.

Comment: Text search for `}` and you'll find the bug in a few seconds...

Comment: please go here : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ 
your style needs some improvments...

Comment: @AK_ you should make it clear that broken code is off topic for Code Review. Thanks.

Comment: @RubberDuck  codereview.stackexchange should start accepting broken code when the main issue is style or horribly broken design.

Comment: @AK_ that's an interesting thought, but I'd point out that design questions are also off topic. Other than that, I would encourage you to post a meta on CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1>** In `case 1:`

```
printf("%s",strconcat(string, string2);break;
```

you're missing a `)` for `printf()`.

**Point 2 >** In `case 4:`

```
 if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                puts("Sao iguais");break;
           else
                puts("Sao diferentes");break;
            }
```

there is mismatch in `{ }`. You don't need them that way. Maybe what you want is

```
 if(stricmp(string, string2)==0)
 {
     puts("Sao iguais");
     break; 
  }
  else
  {
      puts("Sao diferentes");
      break;
   }
```

or, even better,

```
 if(stricmp(string, string2)==0)
     puts("Sao iguais");
  else
      puts("Sao diferentes");

  break;
```

Comment: You do need braces here, otherwise you'll get an `else` without corresponding `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks, the two firsts answer fix it. Btw should i not write code like this? I got the feeling i'm picking some bad habits from my teacher in college

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Oops ! Poor choice of words. Edited. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @Nhull Make your code human-readable. Compilers do not care about white spaces, indentation, textual-readability, but we humans do. Right?  :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yeah you are completely right...i got sloppy -.-" I'm going to optimize it..never should have changed my code writing style in the first place. Teachers in college can do that to you :P

Answer (score 2):

This `if` block has some misplaced curly braces:

```
if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
    puts("Sao iguais");break;
else
    puts("Sao diferentes");break;
}
```

You might want to change it to

```
if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
    puts("Sao iguais");     
}
else {
    puts("Sao diferentes"); 
}
break;
```

***Upd:*** 
Also some other cases have misused `if` blocks (case 3 for instance), like:

```
if(strcmp(string, string2)==0)
    puts("Sao iguais");break;
else
    puts("Sao diferentes");break;
```

Here the `if`and else blocks should be take in `{}`. Or move the `break` after the `if/else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the offending code (missing curly braces near else):

```
               if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                    puts("Sao iguais");break;
               else
                    puts("Sao diferentes");break;
                }
```

You should put each if-else multistatement block inside braces, like this:

```
               if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                    puts("Sao iguais");break;
               } else {
                    puts("Sao diferentes");break;
               }
```

Comment: It's amazing. Our last names are the same.:)

Answer (score 0):

You forget a braces in case 4.

Your Code:

```
if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                    puts("Sao iguais");break;
               else
                    puts("Sao diferentes");break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely wrong.. You miss some brackets, and this program will not work, you have to adjust some things..
In anycase, the correct code for compile is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define TMAXSTR 500

int main(){

char string[TMAXSTR], string2[TMAXSTR];
int option, ch;

for(option=0;ch=0;option<15){

    printf("Escolha uma opção:\n1 - Strconcat (concatenacao de strings)\n2 - Capicua\n3 - Strcmp (Comparacao de Strings)\n4 - Stricmp (transforma caratares em minusculas e compara)\n5 - Strdelc (apaga um determinado caracter)\n6 - Trimright (apaga espaços em branco a direita\n7 - Trimleft (apaga espaços a esquerda\n8 - Trimmiddle (apaga espaços no meio\n9 - Inverter (inverte uma string)\n10 - Findchar (devolve o numero de vezes que um determinado carater aparece na string\n11 - IndiceChar (devolve a posicao de um determinado carater\n12 - Maisculas (Converte a string em maiusculas\n13 - Minusculas (converte a string em minusculas)\n14 - Strstr\n15 - Sair");   

    switch(option){
            case 1:
                   puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                   printf("%s",strconcat(string, string2));
                   break;

            case 2:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   if(capi(string)){
                        puts("E capicua");
                        break;
                        }
                    else{
                        puts("Nao capicua");
                        break;
                        }

            case 3:puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                   if(strcmp(string, string2)==0){
                        puts("Sao iguais");break;}
                   else{
                        puts("Sao diferentes");break;}

            case 4:puts("Introduza a primeira string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);

                   if(stricmp(string, string2)==0){
                        puts("Sao iguais");break;}
                   else{
                        puts("Sao diferentes");break;
                    }

            case 5:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   puts("Introduza o carater a verificar: "); scanf(" %c",&ch);
                   printf("A string sem o carater é: %s",strdelc(string,ch));break;

            case 6:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A nova string é: %s", trimright(string));break;

            case 7:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A nova string é: %s", trimleft(string));break;

            case 8: puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A nova string é: %s", trimmiddle(string));break;

            case 9:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                   printf("A string invertida é: %s", meuinverter(string));break;

            case 10:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("O carater aparece: %dx", findchar(string, ch));break;

            case 11:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    puts("Introduza o carater: "); scanf(" %c",&ch);
                    printf("O indice do carater é: %d", indchr(string,ch));break;

            case 12:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A string em maisculas é: %s", mas(string));break;

            case 13:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    printf("A string em minusculas é: %s", min(string));break;

            case 14:puts("Introduza a string: "); gets(string);
                    puts("Introduza a segunda string: "); gets(string2);
                    printf("%s", mystrstr(string,string2));break;

            default: puts("Invalido");break;        
        }
    }
return 0;}
```